# Force recalculation of keyboard height

Tags: iphone, xcode4.6

This question is linked to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110522/move-view-when-jumping-from-text-field-to-text-field), but this is a more focused part of the problem I'm facing.

I have 5 text fields, and I want to move the (scroll) view so the keyboard doesn't hide the active field. I have implemented keyboardWillShow: text field delegate method as per standard Apple recommended approach, and it works well for when I tap on any text field the first time.

However, I have replaced the Return button on the keyboard with Next button. When it is pressed, the focus jumps onto the next text field. And since the keyboard in the process is neither hidden nor shown again, my keyboardWillShow: method is not called - I see this from the NSLogs I've placed there which are not appearing in console.

Any ideas how I can force the re-calculation of keyboard height when I click Next? One thing I understand is that in order to get the keyboard height (I don't want to use hard-coded heights), I need to keep the calculations in a methods that takes aNotification as an argument.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `keyboardWillShow` is not called as you stated correctly.

Just use `textField:didEndEditing`, or better `textField:shouldBeginEditing` of the next text field, and use the same logic.

To solve the keyboard height and location problem, keep a variable with the data you need and use the usual notification hooks to keep it up to date.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, I can see how this can work. I have another issue though. Field 3 in my form uses a custom view for input, so its height is different from standar keyboard. However, when I use NSLog to see if the new height is captured, it is but with one step lag, i.e. it is captured when I leave that field, not when I enter it, which is very strange, because the detection is done in keyboardWillShow. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Update your variable where you implement your custom input view.